# Youtube - ListChannels with Username (forUsername) is not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get channels info with [ChannelsList](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list). This endpoint has a parameter the name is: `forUsername` but it does not work for this page: https://www.youtube.com/c/FolkartTr

This is my query and it returns empty data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd86q.png]

Somehow, I got this channelID in the page source and its: "**channelId**":"[UCnS--2e1yzQCm5r4ClrMJBg]".
When I try to query with this ID it's okay and returns with correct data.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjCsK.png]

and this is its payload: http://jsonblob.com/941253671862419456

How will I be able to reach this channel info using a username? I got a few links with usernames and I want to get their info with their username. I don't have any chance to get their channelID's for all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, your problem is that you can't do anything from such a `c/` channel id with the [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) of the YouTube Data API v3. If you're just looking for the channel id linked to this id then because as YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work for this, I would recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/c56adf08dd668036004745da318df41a89bfe7ba/channels.php#L32-L37) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?cId=FolkartTr you'll receive a JSON with `id` equals to the channel id linked to the provided `cId` value.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the channel *title* and the channel *customUrl* might be different.

In your example - http://jsonblob.com/941253671862419456 -, the  channel *title* is `Folkart`, but its *customUrl* - which is the value you get when view on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/FolkartTr/featured) -  is: `folkarttr`.

Note the difference in both case-sensitive and additional letters.

For these reasons, you should not based your channel search by name, but, rather, by its `channel_id`.

If you really need to search by userName, the [answer from Benjamin Loison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067222/12511801) can solve your requirement.

See if you can find a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) or post your issue there too. Then, you *might* get some official answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found [an answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308570870#comment7) on their issue tracker. The `forUsername` is for an older username system that is no longer in use and **is not the new @username or /c/username system**. A [search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) request might do the job instead.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube released a revision on 31st January 2024 to add a `forHandle` parameter in the channel list API that does exactly what OP asks.

You can call the channel list API with `forHandle` to get the channel ID and the `upload` playlist for that user/handle that you can subsequently use to fetch the videos.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels

Query parameters:

forHandle=FolkartTr OR @FolkartTr OR %40FolkartTr (this allows the '@' sign as well as URL encoding of it)
key=<your API key>
part=contentDetails
```

The response will be similar to this:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "uIHxDmri3hu046xPYA5kt7Zh_Xs",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "bCWfzhSw3uxD6RCZ7IkkgaPF5Hs",
            "id": "UCnS--2e1yzQCm5r4ClrMJBg",
            "contentDetails": {
                "relatedPlaylists": {
                    "likes": "",
                    "uploads": "UUnS--2e1yzQCm5r4ClrMJBg"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list):

> The forHandle parameter specifies a YouTube handle, thereby requesting the channel associated with that handle. The parameter value can be prepended with an @ symbol. For example, to retrieve the resource for the "Google for Developers" channel, set the forHandle parameter value to either GoogleDevelopers or @GoogleDevelopers.

You can subscribe and/or keep an eye here for the API updates:

https://developers.google.com/static/youtube/v3/feeds/data-api-revision-history.xml