# Youtube - how to get a list of videos in youtube channel and display them as a list?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am browsing the YouTube API here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

And I don't quite see a way to get all of a channel's videos. Is that not a common thing people do? And  you need the channel id which I am not sure how to get. It is not my channel.

Would anyone please be able to point me in the right direction here. It seems that if I can embed a video into a website, I should be able to get the full channel list of videos. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this to retrieve the channel id:

[Retrieve Youtube Channel info for "Vanity" channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593769/retrieve-youtube-channel-info-for-vanity-channel/13595550#13595550)

And later, with channel id you can retrieve  the channel's playlists:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

And then you can use each playlist id to retrieve the PlayListItems, and in this way retrieve all the videoIds in the channel:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems

Comment: thank you! Just to clarify one point, the channel id never changes, right? So once I identify it, I can pull videos by that hardcoded channel id?

Comment: I am able to list all the videos using api **https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet,contentDetails&channelId= UCbTLwN10NoCU4WDzLf1JMOA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}** , Can i get the details of the video like "Uploaded time, duration , view count ...."

Comment: Playlist is not mean uploaded video. You cannot get uploaded video by retreiving video in playlist. Many channel don't have any playlist!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this page from google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to see example how to get uploaded video of specified channel:

1. It retrieves **the playlist ID for videos uploaded** to the user's channel using the API's channels.list method.
2. It passes that ID to the playlistItems.list method to retrieve the videos in that list.