# Youtube api Where will write this code

Tags: youtube-api

Too bad my php knowledge.I'm using YouTube-api.Where will write this code: [Retrieve Youtube Channel info for "Vanity" channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593769/retrieve-youtube-channel-info-for-vanity-channel/13595550#13595550)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this line :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC6ltI41W4P14NShIBHU8z1Q&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You are simply making a get request, you can use `file_get_contents` to get the response for you :

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC6ltI41W4P14NShIBHU8z1Q&key={YOUR_API_KEY}");
```

Two notes :

- You have to replace `{YOUR_API_KEY}` with the developer key. You can easily request one from youtube:  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/
- This is just an example in one line of code, I suggest you use a better approach for making this request like the following :

  ```
  // Encode the parameters of the link
  function encode_param($params) {
      foreach ($params as $field => $value){
          $encoded_params[] = $field . '=' . urlencode($value);
      }
      return $encoded_params;
  }

  // Get the response
  function get_response($url) {
      $response = file_get_contents($url);
      // If error, send message back to the client
      if ($response === false) {
          exit("Couldn't get response from the api");
      }
      return $response;
  }

  $params = array(
          "part" => "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
          "id"   => "UC6ltI41W4P14NShIBHU8",
          "key"  => "-----------", // Your API key
  );

  $encoded_params = encode_param($params);
  $request_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?".implode('&', $encoded_params);
  $response = get_response($request_url);

  //............
  ```