# how to obtain your own channel ID on youtube, using python and youtube API?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-channels

I was wondering how you can obtain your own channel ID using youtube API, or printing a list of the specific channelIDs from your user, since you can have multiple channels on your own user.(im using client_secrets)

i've been watchin alot of the documentation for youtube, but aint finding anything relevant for just this.(maybe im wrong, hehe)

i was watching this:
[How to retrieve a channel id from a channel name or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572657/how-to-retrieve-a-channel-id-from-a-channel-name-or-url)

and that was for a search for every channel, but it should be an easier solution just for your own user.(tell me if im wrong)

and is the right path to go?:

```
channels_list = youtube.channels().list(
    part="id",
    mine=True
  ).execute()
channelID = channel_list["items"]["id"]
```

im going to use the channelId to upload a specific video to the channel.
I hope someone can help!

Comment: You should share your python code. Otherwise your question will be off-topic. Because you asked opinions of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), I'd say you're on the right track.

```
channels_list = youtube.channels().list(mine=True)
```

Should return a list of your owned channels, if you're sending an authenticated `request`.

You can then simply access the list directly by calling

```
channels_list['items']
```

Note that the `ChannelItem` is a dict within a list, so you'll have to access the channel item's `index`, and then the `key`

```
channels_list['items'][0]['items']['id']
```

If you'd like to get your channel ids in a single step, this might be what you're looking for:

```
chan_ids = [chan['items']['id'] for chan in youtube.channels().list(mine=True)['items']]
```

[This section here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) might be of help to you, as well.

Comment: All this said, I don't have keys to do authenticated requests, but alas, I hope this was helpful anyway.